# Can't swap two objects from Object Array

Tags: c++, arrays

Im currently making a Line3 type of game and I have a problem when trying to swap two Objects in the array. My game has 2 classes : the Gem class, which are the thing you must line up to get points and the Board class, which contain a Gem array[6][6].

The problem is with my swap method. Inside the method, I have some cout to help me see and the swap is actually done, but I think i'm doing it on a copy cause after that, when I refresh my Board, the Gems are not interchanged. Here's is my code, feel free to make any suggestions :

**Board.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Gem.h"

    class Board
    {
    public:
        Board();
        ~Board();

        void gameLoop();
        void refreshGameGrid();
        void refillGameGrid();
        void checkIfStacks();
        void swapGems(Gem& p_firstGem, Gem& p_secondGem);
        Gem getGem(int line, int column);

    private:
        Gem m_gameGrid[6][6];
    };
```

**Board.CPP**

```
// Swap the position of two Gems on the Board.
    void Board::swapGems(Gem& p_firstGem, Gem& p_secondGem)
    {
        cout <<"Avant : " << p_firstGem.getRepresentation() << " | " << p_secondGem.getRepresentation() << endl;
        p_firstGem.switchWith(p_secondGem);
        cout << "Après : " << p_firstGem.getRepresentation() << " | " << p_secondGem.getRepresentation() << endl;
    }
```

**Gem.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "gemMania.h"

class Gem
{
public:
    Gem();
    ~Gem();

    // Getters
    const string& getRepresentation();
    const string& getColor();
    const string& getPosition();
    int getNumberOfGems();

    // Setters
    void setColorAndRepr(const string&, const string&);
    //Methods
    void switchWith(Gem&);
    void destroyGem();
    void renewGem();

private:
    string m_representation;
    string m_color;
    string m_position;
    static int numberOfGems;

};
```

**Gem.cpp**

```
// Switch the attrbutes of two gems, hence swaping the two of them.
void Gem::switchWith(Gem& p_otherGem)
{
    swap(this->m_color, p_otherGem.m_color);
    swap(this->m_representation, p_otherGem.m_representation);
}
```

[Picture of what's happening in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTATI.png)

Thanks alot in advance for everyone that will take the time to help me !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My ***guess***? That you pass the instance of `Board` *by value* somewhere.

Comment: The only place where I construct a Board object is in main : 

Board gameBoard;
gameBoard.gameLoop();

Comment: You left out the call where you pass objects to the function. `getGem` returns a `Gem` by value; you're modifying those copies.

Comment: So what should I change? I always had problems understanding pointers well, like should I add a * somewhere?

Comment: @CharlesBinet You could return by reference, `Gem&`. Personally, I would rewrite `swapGems` to take two coordinates instead of two `Gem`s.

Comment: Oh god it worked, I added the & reference symbol to my method declaration like so : 

Gem& ... 

and it worked, thanks alot guys !

Comment: @molbdnilo, I though doing so, but gameBoard[i][j] returns a Gem, and my coordinate system is based of the gameBoard[i][j], so would that make sense not to ?